# How can I remove CRLF if anywhere between double quotes, using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

My text file looks like this.

```
"MikeCRLF","","","Dell","DevelCRLFCRLFoper"CRLF
"SuCRLFsan","","","Apple","ManagCRLFer"CRLF
```

Desired result:

```
"Mike","","","Dell","Developer"LF
"Susan","","","Apple","Manager"LF
```

I tried this on PowerShell:

```
"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\1.txt"
(Get-Content $path -Raw).Replace("`r`n","`n") | Set-Content $path -Force
```

When I do this, I don't get the desired result. Also, I am left with one CRLF at the end. I don't want that either.

Please tell me how to do this using PowerShell v3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method avoids checking to see if `\r\n` is in quotes. Instead, it tries to find the "real" end of line situations and converts those first. Then it just purges the rest.

```
(Get-Content test.txt -Raw) -replace  '([^,]")(\s*\r\n\s*)+("[^,])',"`$1`n`$3" -replace '\r\n',''
```

I think this should handle most of the stuff you throw at it, but let me know if you find a special case.

*edited to fix the replacement string*

Comment: what does this '([^,]")(\s*\r\n\s*)+("[^,])',"`$1`n`$3" mean and what is that `$1`n`$3?

Comment: `([^,]")` = Look for a quote that's not preceded by a comma  
`(\s*\r\n\s*)+` = Find one or more CRLF strings, optionally padded with spaces  
`("[^,])` = Look for a quote that's not followed by a comma  
`$1\n$3` = Replace it with what you found in the first group, a line feed (`\n`) and what you found in the third group. You have to add the groups in order to preserve the content around the quotes. That could be replaced with a lookahead/lookbehind, but I wasn't sure if powershell could deal with those since I never use it.

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting in my comment. I did the two space before a newline thing, but it still combined everything into one hideous line. I went beyond the 5 minute editing window now so I can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com), you can use the ConvertTo-UnixLineEnding command e.g.:

```
ConvertTo-UnixLineEnding C:\users\abc\desktop1.txt -dest desktop1-converted.txt -Enc ascii
```

Comment: The problem is that he has newlines in the middle of his actual content. He can't just change everything from `\r\n` to `\n`

Comment: @Desidero: you are correct, i have new lines \r\n in between...so simply trying to replace all \r\n with \n will not help.